# Call mongoexport from javascript Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv, export-to-csv

I would like to export a Mongo Collection to an .csv. Mongo provides a solution for this but it is limited to the shell.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoexport/

I'm using the native driver for node.js and would like to be able to do this in a script as opposed to being invoked from the shell.

Comment: Did you find a way? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking to run the `mongoexport` command from your node.js app, you can use [`child_process.spawn`](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) to do that.

Comment: Is there any way to do this from a client? If you're running mongo from a remote instance, you don't have the file structure to get the bin functions.

Comment: No, it's a separately utility and not supported by the node.js driver.