# mongoexport collection using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoexport

I am currently experiencing a major headache (for a middle-aged duffer, that is).
My current problem is this:
I have to use D3.js to visualise data stored in a local MongoDB database. I have the visualisation pretty much sorted, just one or two minors, but I think I can sort them.
My problem is actually getting the data out of the database. I can import and export to my heart’s content using the shell, but I need to automate the process. The step I am having no progress with is this: Using Node.js, I can connect to my local MongoDB databse with the following script:

```
**

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, format = require('util').format;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017' function(err,db){   
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else{
        console.log("Connected");
    }
    db.close();
});
```

**

Whilst I am connected, I need to export one of three collections (newYork, manchester or london) , as a .json array, from a database called monopoly.
I have to use javascript and I need to export an entire collection to a folder location that I can choose, which will allow me to direct my D3.js to it
I think mongoexport is the method I want as when I try this from the mongo shell, I get exactly what I want
Any enlightenment would be gratefully received
Thanks
S

Comment: Can you simply query the data that you want and then us `fs` to write the returned json to a file?

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I need to eventually query the database from the  web page.

Comment: I'm really confused. If you need to query the data from the webpage, then you'll need to spin up a mongodb and get the data off your localhost.

If you're looking to use mongoexport from within node, [this answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041648/call-mongoexport-from-javascript-node-js). [Or this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176232/mongoexport-with-parameters-node-js-child-process/20176549)

Answer (score 4):

This documentation might help.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

Try this

```
    app.get('/export', function(req, res)
    {
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        ls = spawn('mongoexport',['--db','monopoly','--collection','newYork']);
        res.sendfile('/home/database.csv') 

    });
```